# Trying to Query remote WordPress database

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, remote-access

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a remote Wordpress site (to another Wordpress site), the code below returns an empty array, if I use the local database (just comment out the first line of code) it returns posts. Preferably I'd like to be able to run a `WP_Query` on the remote database, but that's just a bonus.

```
        $wpdb = new wpdb( $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname, $dbhost );

        $wpdb->set_prefix('wp_');
        $wpdb->show_errors();

        $psts = $wpdb->get_row( 
            "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts"
        );
```

**EDIT:**
I've discovered that if I change the query to `"SELECT * FROM wp_posts"` I get a result. So I guess it's a PHP version thing (I run 5.4.4 and server runs 5.3.3)? Still can't run a WP-Query though.

**EDIT 2:**
I just realized I've left out one important piece of information: the site I'm running the Query from is a **multi site** install! I'm sure this could affect they how the querys are formed!

Comment: Could be anything. We need more info. Is the host reachable? Does any data exist in the remote db, etc.

Comment: The database has content and I can reach it from my local computers sql program using the same credentials.

Comment: read my answer below. Maybe your Remote DB is only accessible by localhost? (phpmyadmin - rights )

Comment: By my local computer I meant the cpu here at the office :) - I shoudln't be able to connect frpm here of only localhost was allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Check if:

- Remote DB is **reachable**
- Your user has **rights** on the remote DB/Table
- Your Remote DB is not only **accessible** by localhost (if so, enter a **%** instead of localhost)

Answer (score 1):

If you owner of source wordpress website please follow the instruction:

1. Create a php file inside source wordpress root directory named remotequery.php or you like best
2. load wordpress library including "required ('wp-load.php')" at the top of file

   So it will something like this

`<?php 
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); // Don't load theme support functionality
require( 'wp-load.php' );
?>`

Then you can add any wordpress query, you no need add database correction. you can add wordpress style database query to retrieve data from  wordpress database.

Answer (score 0):

[See this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)...

If both the sites are yours, and you want data from other site than you can get data in `json format` with this plugin...

This plugin is quite help full...

Hope this will help...

Answer (score 0):

You can also used the PHP CURL library for the remote connection.

is the one way
or we also used Ajax using the data type jsonp
that can connect to remove server using Ajax.
Please used below URL:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_jsonp_retrieve_data.ashx
or
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/